# How to implement date picker in lwuit?

Tags: java-me, datepicker, lwuit, midp-2.0, cldc

I'm developing a mobile app using j2me and lwuit.

There is a lcdui DateField (act as date picker) in j2me. Like that there is any component or item in lwuit.

How to implement the date picker (Similar to lcdui DateField) in lwuit.

The calendar (in lwuit) object is not user friendly. If phone screen size is small then it will not be correctly shown. In normal j2me (lcdui) the datefield has very good look. I want to create a component/item like that in lwuit (using lwuit in j2me).

Comment: Dear,All ,The calendar (in lwuit) object is not user friendly.If phone screen size is small then it will not correctly shown.In normal j2me (lcdui) the datefield is very good look.I want to create a component/item like that in lwuit (using lwuit in j2me).Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lcdui` `DateField` in `lwuit`. I do it by this way:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.CommandListener;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.DateField;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;

import com.sun.lwuit.Button;
import com.sun.lwuit.Display;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener;
import com.sun.lwuit.plaf.UIManager;

public class DatePicker extends Button implements ActionListener {

  private static final String OK = "ok";
  private static final String CANCEL = "cancel";

  private Date date;

  public DatePicker() {
    setUIID("TextArea");
    addActionListener(this);
  }

  public Date getDate() {
    return date;
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    final Form dateForm = new Form();
    final DateField dateField = new DateField(null, DateField.DATE);
    if (date != null) {
      dateField.setDate(date);
    }
    dateForm.append(dateField);
    final javax.microedition.lcdui.Command acceptCommand = new javax.microedition.lcdui.Command(UIManager.getInstance().localize(OK, OK),
    javax.microedition.lcdui.Command.OK, 0);
    final javax.microedition.lcdui.Command cancelCommand = new javax.microedition.lcdui.Command(UIManager.getInstance().localize(CANCEL, CANCEL), javax.microedition.lcdui.Command.CANCEL, 0);
    dateForm.addCommand(acceptCommand);
    dateForm.addCommand(cancelCommand);
    CommandListener commandListener = new CommandListener() {
      public void commandAction(javax.microedition.lcdui.Command command, Displayable displayable) { 
        if (command == acceptCommand && dateField.getDate() != null) {
          DatePicker.this.date = dateField.getDate();
          DatePicker.this.setText(DatePicker.toString(DatePicker.this.date));
        }
        Display.init(Application.getInstance().midlet); // You have to save your midlet
        Application.getInstance().mainForm.show();      // and the last lwuit Form
      }
    };
    dateForm.setCommandListener(commandListener);
    javax.microedition.lcdui.Display.getDisplay(Application.getInstance().midlet).setCurrent(dateForm);  // Application.getInstance().midlet - your j2me application midlet

  }      
}
```

So now you can use it like `lwuit` `Component`, but on the `actionPerformed` it will open `lcdui` native `Form` with `DateField` on the top.

Comment: I would like to use this component, but I get errors on the final Form dateForm = new Form(); (not suitable constructor o_O), here DatePicker.this.setText(DatePicker.toString(DatePicker.this.date)); and getting the Application object

Comment: 1) Check your imports. The Form class must be javax.microedition.lcdui.Form, but I suppose your Form is lwuit.Form
2) Application object is important for my application. But you can use something else, to save MIDlet object. And you can replace "Application.getInstance().mainForm.show();" with Display.getInsnace().restoreMinimizedApplication();

Comment: The Form is correctly imported....i will try with the diplay.getInstance instead Application object

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a calender extending component and it work fine in LWUIT and the code I used as follows

```
public class Calendar extends Container {

    private ComboBox month;
    private ComboBox year;
    private MonthView mv;
    private static final String[] MONTHS = new String[]{"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    private static final String[] DAYS = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    private static final String[] LABELS = {"Su", "M", "Tu", "W", "Th", "F", "Sa"};
    static final long MINUTE = 1000 * 60;
    static final long HOUR = MINUTE * 60;
    static final long DAY = HOUR * 24;
    static final long WEEK = DAY * 7;
    private EventDispatcher dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
    private EventDispatcher dataChangeListeners = new EventDispatcher();
    private long[] dates = new long[42];
    private boolean changesSelectedDateEnabled = true;
    private TimeZone tmz;

    private static ComboListCellRenderer comboListCellRenderer = new ComboListCellRenderer();;

    private int[] bgColorArray = new int[]{0x2E9AFE, 0x39FEB6, 0x39FEB6};

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of Calendar set to the given date based on time
     * since epoch (the java.util.Date convention)
     *
     * @param time time since epoch
     */
    public Calendar(int[] bgColorArray, ListCellRenderer listCellRenderer, long time) {
        this(bgColorArray, listCellRenderer, time, java.util.TimeZone.getDefault());
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a calendar with the current date and time
     */
    public Calendar(int[] bgColorArray, ListCellRenderer listCellRenderer) {
        this(bgColorArray, listCellRenderer, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a calendar with the current date and time
     */
    public Calendar() {

        this(null, comboListCellRenderer, System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of Calendar set to the given date based on time
     * since epoch (the java.util.Date convention)
     *
     * @param time time since epoch
     * @param tmz a reference timezone
     */
    public Calendar(int[] bgColorArray, ListCellRenderer listCellRenderer, long time, TimeZone tmz) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        if(bgColorArray != null)
            this.bgColorArray = bgColorArray;
        this.tmz = tmz;
        setUIID("Calendar");
        Container upper = new Container(new FlowLayout(Component.CENTER));
        month = new ComboBox();
        year = new ComboBox();
        mv = new MonthView(time);

        Vector months = new Vector();
        for (int i = 0; i < MONTHS.length; i++) {
            months.addElement("" + getLocalizedMonth(i));
        }

        ListModel monthsModel = new DefaultListModel(months);
        int selected = months.indexOf(getLocalizedMonth(mv.getMonth()));
        month.setModel(monthsModel);
        month.setSelectedIndex(selected);
        month.addActionListener(mv);

        if(listCellRenderer != null){
             month.setListCellRenderer(listCellRenderer);
             year.setListCellRenderer(listCellRenderer);
        }

        month.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[1]);
        month.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[0]);
        month.getPressedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[2]);

        year.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[1]);
        year.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[0]);
        year.getPressedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[2]);

      /*  month.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(0xff00000);
        year.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(0xff00000);
        ComboListCellRenderer comboListCellRenderer = new ComboListCellRenderer();

        */

        java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(tmz);
        cal.setTime(new java.util.Date(time));
        month.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
        int y = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
        Vector years = new Vector();
        for (int i = 2100; i > 1900; i--) {
            years.addElement("" + i);
        }
        ListModel yearModel = new DefaultListModel(years);
        selected = years.indexOf("" + y);
        year.setModel(yearModel);
        year.setSelectedIndex(selected);
        year.getStyle().setBgTransparency(0);
        year.addActionListener(mv);
        Container cnt = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        cnt.setRTL(false);

        Container dateCnt = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        dateCnt.setUIID("CalendarDate");
        dateCnt.addComponent(month);
        dateCnt.addComponent(year);
        cnt.addComponent(dateCnt);
        upper.addComponent(cnt);

        addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, upper);
        addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, mv);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the time for the current calendar.
     *
     * @return the time for the current calendar.
     */
    public long getSelectedDay() {
        return mv.getSelectedDay();
    }

    private String getLocalizedMonth(int i) {
        Hashtable t = UIManager.getInstance().getResourceBundle();
        String text = MONTHS[i];
        if (t != null) {
            Object o = t.get("Calendar." + text);
            if (o != null) {
                text = (String) o;
            }
        }
        return text;
    }

    void componentChanged() {
        java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(tmz);
        cal.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, mv.getYear());
        cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, mv.getMonth());
        cal.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mv.getDayOfMonth());
        month.getParent().revalidate();
    }

    /**
     * Return the date object matching the current selection
     *
     * @return the date object matching the current selection
     */
    public Date getDate() {
        return new Date(mv.getSelectedDay());
    }

    /**
     * Sets the current date in the view and the selected date to be the same.
     *
     * @param d new date
     */
    public void setDate(Date d) {
        mv.setSelectedDay(d.getTime());
        mv.setCurrentDay(mv.currentDay, true);
        componentChanged();
    }

    /**
     * This method sets the Calendar selected day
     * @param d the selected day
     */
    public void setSelectedDate(Date d){
        mv.setSelectedDay(d.getTime());
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Calendar view on the given date, only the the month and year
     * are being considered.
     *
     * @param d the date to set the calendar view on.
     */
    public void setCurrentDate(Date d){
        mv.setCurrentDay(d.getTime(), true);
        componentChanged();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the Calendar timezone, if not specified Calendar will use the
     * default timezone
     * @param tmz the timezone
     */
    public void setTimeZone(TimeZone tmz){
        this.tmz = tmz;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the Calendar timezone
     *
     * @return Calendar TimeZone
     */
    public TimeZone getTimeZone(){
        return tmz;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the selected style of the month view component within the calendar
     *
     * @param s style for the month view
     */
    public void setMonthViewSelectedStyle(Style s) {
        mv.setSelectedStyle(s);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the un selected style of the month view component within the calendar
     *
     * @param s style for the month view
     */
    public void setMonthViewUnSelectedStyle(Style s) {
        mv.setUnselectedStyle(s);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the selected style of the month view component within the calendar
     *
     * @return the style of the month view
     */
    public Style getMonthViewSelectedStyle() {
        return mv.getSelectedStyle();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the un selected style of the month view component within the calendar
     *
     * @return the style of the month view
     */
    public Style getMonthViewUnSelectedStyle() {
        return mv.getUnselectedStyle();
    }

    /**
     * Fires when a change is made to the month view of this component
     *
     * @param l listener to add
     */
    public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        mv.addActionListener(l);
    }

    /**
     * Fires when a change is made to the month view of this component
     *
     * @param l listener to remove
     */
    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        mv.removeActionListener(l);
    }

    /**
     * Allows tracking selection changes in the calendar in real time
     *
     * @param l listener to add
     */
    public void addDataChangeListener(DataChangedListener l) {
        mv.addDataChangeListener(l);
    }

    /**
     * Allows tracking selection changes in the calendar in real time
     *
     * @param l listener to remove
     */
    public void removeDataChangeListener(DataChangedListener l) {
        mv.removeDataChangeListener(l);
    }

    /**
     * This flag determines if selected date can be changed by selecting an
     * alternative date
     *
     * @param changesSelectedDateEnabled if true pressing on a date will cause
     * the selected date to be changed to the pressed one
     */
    public void setChangesSelectedDateEnabled(boolean changesSelectedDateEnabled) {
        this.changesSelectedDateEnabled = changesSelectedDateEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * This flag determines if selected date can be changed by selecting an
     * alternative date
     *
     * @return true if enabled
     */
    public boolean isChangesSelectedDateEnabled() {
        return changesSelectedDateEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * This method creates the Day Button Component for the Month View
     *
     * @return a Button that corresponds to the Days Components
     */
    protected Button createDay() {
        Button day = new Button();
        day.setAlignment(CENTER);
        day.setUIID("CalendarDay");
        day.setEndsWith3Points(false);
        day.setTickerEnabled(false);
        return day;
    }

    /**
     * This method creates the Day title Component for the Month View
     *
     * @param day the relevant day values are 0-6 where 0 is sunday.
     * @return a Label that corresponds to the relevant Day
     */
    protected Label createDayTitle(int day) {
        String value = UIManager.getInstance().localize("Calendar." + DAYS[day], LABELS[day]);
        Label dayh = new Label(value, "CalendarTitle");
        dayh.setEndsWith3Points(false);
        dayh.setTickerEnabled(false);
        return dayh;
    }

    /**
     * This method updates the Button day.
     *
     * @param dayButton the button to be updated
     * @param day the new button day
     */
    protected void updateButtonDayDate(Button dayButton, int currentMonth, int day) {
        dayButton.setText("" + day);
    }

        class MonthView extends Container implements ActionListener{

        private long currentDay;
        private Button[] buttons = new Button[42];
        private Button selected;
        private long selectedDay = -1;

        public MonthView(long time) {
            super(new GridLayout(7, 7));
            setUIID("MonthView");
            for (int iter = 0; iter < DAYS.length; iter++) {
                addComponent(createDayTitle(iter));
            }
            for (int iter = 0; iter < buttons.length; iter++) {
                buttons[iter] = createDay();

                addComponent(buttons[iter]);
                if (iter <= 7) {
                    buttons[iter].setNextFocusUp(year);
                }
                buttons[iter].addActionListener(this);
            }
            setCurrentDay(time);

        }

        public void setCurrentDay(long day){
            setCurrentDay(day, false);
        }

        private void setCurrentDay(long day, boolean force) {
            repaint();
            java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(tmz);
            cal.setTime(new Date(currentDay));
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 1);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            int yearOld = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
            int monthOld = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
            int dayOld = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            cal.setTime(new Date(day));
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 1);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            int yearNew = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
            int monthNew = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
            int dayNew = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            year.setSelectedItem("" + yearNew);
            month.setSelectedIndex(monthNew);

            if (yearNew != yearOld || monthNew != monthOld || dayNew != dayOld || force) {
                currentDay = cal.getTime().getTime();
                if(selectedDay == -1){
                    selectedDay = currentDay;
                }
                int month = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
                cal.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                long startDate = cal.getTime().getTime();
                int dow = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                cal.setTime(new Date(cal.getTime().getTime() - DAY));
                cal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 1);
                cal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
                cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                cal.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                int lastDay = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int i = 0;
                if(dow > java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY){
                    //last day of previous month

                    while (dow > java.util.Calendar.SUNDAY) {
                        cal.setTime(new Date(cal.getTime().getTime() - DAY));
                        dow = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                    }
                    int previousMonthSunday = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    for (; i <= lastDay - previousMonthSunday; i++) {
                        buttons[i].setUIID("CalendarDay");
                        buttons[i].setEnabled(false);

                        buttons[i].setText("" + (previousMonthSunday + i));
                    }
                }
                //last day of current month
                cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, (month + 1) % 12);
                cal.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                cal.setTime(new Date(cal.getTime().getTime() - DAY));

                lastDay = cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                int j = i;
                for (; j < buttons.length && (j - i + 1) <= lastDay; j++) {
                    buttons[j].setEnabled(true);
                    dates[j] = startDate;
                    if(dates[j] == selectedDay){
                        buttons[j].setUIID("CalendarSelectedDay");
                        selected = buttons[j];
                    }else{
                        buttons[j].setUIID("CalendarDay");
                    }
                    buttons[j].getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[1]);
                    buttons[j].getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[0]);
                    buttons[j].getPressedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[2]);

                    buttons[j].getStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(
                            Font.FACE_PROPORTIONAL, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
                    buttons[j].getSelectedStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(
                            Font.FACE_PROPORTIONAL, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
                    buttons[j].getUnselectedStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(
                            Font.FACE_PROPORTIONAL, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
                    buttons[j].getPressedStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(
                            Font.FACE_PROPORTIONAL, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
                    updateButtonDayDate(buttons[j], month, j - i + 1);
                    startDate += DAY;
                }
                int d = 1;
                for (; j < buttons.length; j++) {
                    buttons[j].setUIID("CalendarDay");
                    buttons[j].setEnabled(false);
                    buttons[j].setText("" + d++);

                    buttons[j].getStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(
                            Font.FACE_PROPORTIONAL, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
                    buttons[j].getSelectedStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(
                            Font.FACE_PROPORTIONAL, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
                    buttons[j].getUnselectedStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(
                            Font.FACE_PROPORTIONAL, Font.STYLE_BOLD, Font.SIZE_SMALL));
                    buttons[j].getPressedStyle().setFont(Font.createSystemFont(
                            Font.FACE_PROPORTIONAL, Font.STYLE_PLAIN, Font.SIZE_SMALL));

                }
            }
        }

        public int getDayOfMonth() {
            java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(tmz);
            cal.setTime(new Date(currentDay));
            return cal.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }

        public int getMonth() {
            java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(tmz);
            cal.setTime(new Date(currentDay));
            return cal.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
        }

        public void incrementMonth() {
            int month = getMonth();
            month++;
            int year = getYear();
            if (month > java.util.Calendar.DECEMBER) {
                month = java.util.Calendar.JANUARY;
                year++;
            }
            setMonth(year, month);
        }

        private long getSelectedDay() {
            return selectedDay;
        }

        public void setSelectedDay(long selectedDay){
            java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(tmz);
            cal.setTime(new Date(selectedDay));
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 1);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            this.selectedDay = cal.getTime().getTime();
        }

        private void setMonth(int year, int month) {
            java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(tmz);
            cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.MONTH, month);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            cal.set(java.util.Calendar.YEAR, year);

            Date date = cal.getTime();
            long d = date.getTime();

            // if this is past the last day of the month (e.g. going from January 31st
            // to Febuary) we need to decrement the day until the month is correct
            while (cal.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH) != month) {
                d -= DAY;
                cal.setTime(new Date(d));
            }
            setCurrentDay(d);
        }

        public void decrementMonth() {
            int month = getMonth();
            month--;
            int year = getYear();
            if (month < java.util.Calendar.JANUARY) {
                month = java.util.Calendar.DECEMBER;
                year--;
            }
            setMonth(year, month);
        }

        public int getYear() {
            java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance(tmz);
            cal.setTime(new Date(currentDay));
            return cal.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
        }

        public void addActionListener(ActionListener l) {
            dispatcher.addListener(l);
        }

        public void removeActionListener(ActionListener l) {
            dispatcher.removeListener(l);
        }

        /**
         * Allows tracking selection changes in the calendar in real time
         *
         * @param l listener to add
         */
        public void addDataChangeListener(DataChangedListener l) {
            dataChangeListeners.addListener(l);
        }

        /**
         * Allows tracking selection changes in the calendar in real time
         *
         * @param l listener to remove
         */
        public void removeDataChangeListener(DataChangedListener l) {
            dataChangeListeners.removeListener(l);
        }

        protected void fireActionEvent() {
            componentChanged();
            super.fireActionEvent();
            dispatcher.fireActionEvent(new ActionEvent(Calendar.this));
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Object src = evt.getSource();
            if(src instanceof ComboBox){
                setMonth(Integer.parseInt((String)year.getSelectedItem()),
                        month.getSelectedIndex());
                componentChanged();
                return;
            }
            if(changesSelectedDateEnabled){
                System.out.println("ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt");
                for (int iter = 0; iter < buttons.length; iter++) {
                    if (src == buttons[iter]) {
                        selected.setUIID("CalendarDay");
                        buttons[iter].setUIID("CalendarSelectedDay");
                        selectedDay = dates[iter];

                        selected.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[1]);
                        selected.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[0]);
                        selected.getPressedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[2]);

                        selected = buttons[iter];

                        selected.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[1]);
                        selected.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[0]);
                        selected.getPressedStyle().setBgColor(bgColorArray[2]);


                        fireActionEvent();
                        if (!getComponentForm().isSingleFocusMode()) {
                            setHandlesInput(false);
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ComboListCellRender is not implemented